# What exactly happens in the "graphic setup" of postfix?

Tags: postfix, ansible

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) on how to install and configure postfix, but using Ansible instead of a plain installation. Because of using Ansible, I do not get the following steps of the "graphical setup" like in a regular `apt install`:

[image]

[image]

I assume these settings map to certain configuration changes in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` or other config files. I'd like to apply the corresponding changes manually in my Ansible playbook. What are the equivalent configuration changes of these two settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setup is part of the Debian package for Postfix.

Take a look at the [ansible.builtin.debconf](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debconf_module.html) Module, using that you can have Ansible run apt with the right configuration options (the same as you would enter with that dialog).

For example:

```
- name: Select Postfix config
  ansible.builtin.debconf:
    name: postfix
    question: postfix/main_mailer_type
    value: Internet Site
    vtype: select
```

If you really want to dig into it then you can find the [sources for the config scripts](https://sources.debian.org/src/postfix/3.4.14-0+deb10u1/debian/), most importantly the `postfix.config` and `templates`; but that should not be necessary.